# Can I use a property placeholder in a Spring 3 bean's id attribute in the XML configuration?

Tags: spring, configuration, properties

I have an application that is in the process of being migrated to a new setup. The current interim is that the application is being deployed onto the same GlassFish server but with different configuration (property files, jndi, etc). In my Spring 3 configuration, I am using the task namespace for scheduling, but I want to know if there is a problem if all deployments of the application can have the same id for the scheduler, ie:

```
<task:scheduler id="appScheduler" pool-size="10" />
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="appScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="notificationSender" method="sendNotifications" cron="${email.time.cron}" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

If not, is there a way to put a placeholder in the scheduler's id attribute so each application has its own, ie:

```
<task:scheduler id="${app.name}Scheduler" pool-size="10" />
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="${app.name}Scheduler">
    ...
```

I did try the above, but the error message kept coming back about not being able to find the referenced scheduler after the property was substituted. Thus raises the question, will Spring substitute a property inside the id attribute?